# Gunicorn when use .conf file and when use python config file

Tags: linux, shell, nginx, gunicorn

I am taking online course on web technologies and one of the most recent tasks is to launch python app on gunicorn server through nginx proxy on remote linux VM.

Task description says: Configure Gunicorn so that it runs the /home/box/web/hello.py application and accepts connections on the 0.0.0.0:8080. (IP = 0.0.0.0 is required for testing). Put your config file here /home/box/etc/gunicorn.conf and connect it using the symbolic link /etc/gunicorn.d/test.

I found the solution on the Internet (I understand, that cheating is bad) and gunicorn.conf file looks like this:

```
CONFIG = {
'mode': 'wsgi',
'working_dir': '/home/box/web',
'python': '/usr/bin/python',
'args': (
'--bind=0.0.0.0:8080',
'--workers=2',
'--timeout=15',
'--log-level=debug',
'hello:application'
)
}
```

It seems that author of that solution borrowed it from [here](https://scottlinux.com/2014/04/03/how-to-host-multiple-django-or-python-apps-on-the-same-host-with-nginx-and-gunicorn/). Gunicorn and nginx are supposed to run using following shell script:

```
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sudo ln -sf /home/box/web/etc/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.conf
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
sudo ln -sf /home/box/web/etc/gunicorn.conf /etc/gunicorn.d/test
sudo /etc/init.d/gunicorn restart
```

I wonder where does that .conf file syntax described and why does not use gunicorn config file as described [here](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/configure.html) as I initially assumed. And what does all that stuff with symbolic links required for? Can I solve this task using python-style gunocrn config if I modify shell script. If so what are pros and cons of each way?